# Where to define table/entity classes when using the standalone CakePHP ORM?

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0, autoload, cakephp-3.x

I am using the standalone sub-project 'cakephp-ORM' of cakephp
[CakePHP-orm](https://github.com/cakephp/orm).

I cannot find in the documentation where on the filesystem to define tables and entities.

It is explained how to create tables, but not where to save them to. Will the table then be called on autoload or do you have to require / include them yourself? [Documentation chapter](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to create an issue [**over at GitHub**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues), as the documentation for standalone usage surely could be improved.

### The conventions are similar to those for a CakePHP app

When used standalone, the ORM will by default lookup table and entity classes in the `Model\Table` and `Model\Entity` namespace, and table classes are expected to use a `Table` suffix. So using `$locator->get('Articles')` will look for `\Model\Table\ArticlesTable`, and if such a table class exists, the respective entity class will be looked up as `\Model\Entity\Article`.

These are pretty much the same conventions that exists when the ORM is used in a CakePHP application, except that in a CakePHP application there is usually a base namespace that is configured via the `App.namespace` configuration option. You can use that with the standalone ORM too, ie if you do:

```
\Cake\Core\Configure::write('App.namespace', 'MyApp');
```

it will be picked up and prepended when looking up classes, given the example above, that would be `\MyApp\Model\Table\ArticlesTable` and `\MyApp\Model\Entity\Article`. When such classes do not exist, the ORM will use so called generic/auto-tables, that is instances of `\Cake\ORM\Table` and `\Cake\ORM\Entity` instead of concrete subclasses thereof.

### Autoloading is up to you

Where you place the files in the filesystem is completely up to you, you just need to make sure that they are auto-loadable via those names. If you for example use PSR-4 autoloading like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "MyApp\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

then the respective files would be `src/Model/Table/ArticlesTable.php` and `src/Model/Entity/Article.php`, and you'd configure the base namespace as shown above.

### You can use fully qualified names instead of reyling on naming conventions

It's also possible to use FQNs for tables and entities, for example:

```
$table = $locator->get('Articles', [
    'className' => \Custom\Fully\Qualified\Name\To\ArticlesTable::class
]);
```

The custom FQN for the entity and associations can be set in the respective table class:

```
namespace Custom\Fully\Qualified\Name\To;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class ArticlesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->setEntityClass(\Custom\Fully\Qualified\Name\To\Article::class);

        $this->hasMany('Comments', [
            'className' => \Custom\Fully\Qualified\Name\To\CommentsTable::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

So `$table` will be an instance of `\Custom\Fully\Qualified\Name\To\ArticlesTable`,  querying records will return `\Custom\Fully\Qualified\Name\To\Article` instances, and containing `Comments` will use `\Custom\Fully\Qualified\Name\To\CommentsTable`.

### See also

With that in mind you should be able to refer to the CakePHP ORM docs for further usage.

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm.html)**

Comment: setting the className param for the $locator-get method was enough for me, setting the full name in the Table class was not necessary. The content of this answer should be added to the Cookbook

Comment: Issue opened: https://github.com/cakephp/orm/issues/15 thanks for the solution :)

Comment: @ndm is it not required to wrap the `setEntityClass` arguments with quotes? At least [according to the docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#customizing-the-entity-class-a-table-uses)? Not doing that gives me *Error: Undefined constant 'App\Model\Entity\MyClass*

Comment: @aexl It is not required if you target [**the `::class` constant**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class) (you've probably omitted that), which will resolve to a fully qualified name string at compile time. Using the `::class` syntax over defining strings is especially useful for refactoring support, and inside of namespaces so that you don't have to write out the full name.

Answer (score 1):

according to 
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm.html
all you have to do is to extend your Table from `Cake\ORM\Table` and as long as the table is autoloaded (i.e comes from a composer package) or loaded manually (i.e via include) it should be recognized by the `TableRegistry`.

i.e this simple example php file using `cake-orm` as the only composer dependency (my example loads the custom model manually):

```
<?php

include('vendor/autoload.php');

include 'App/Models/Table/ExamplesTable.php';

use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

ConnectionManager::setConfig('default', [
    'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
    'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
    'database' => 'cakephpormtest',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'cacheMetadata' => false,
    'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
]);

// Now $examples is an array of Cake\ORM\Entity instances.
$examples = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Examples')->query()->toArray();
var_dump($examples);
```

I wouldn't expect standalone library to tell you where should you store your files, so I think the best answer is: put your table models where you want. How you structure your project and load your classes is up to you. I'd still refer to global best practices in programming when doing this, but that's all :)